# var newEvent=$.extend($.Event("click"). its work in chrome but not in Mozilla

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, eventtrigger, mousedown

I create new jquery Event for trigger,

its work in google chrome but its not work in mozilla
.
.
here is code.

```
jQuery("#calendar").mousedown(function(e){
 if(e.button === 2) {
   var newEvent = $.extend($.Event("click"), {
    which: 1,
    clientX: event.clientX,
    clientY: event.clientY,
    pageX: event.pageX,
    pageY: event.pageY,
    screenX: event.screenX,
    screenY: event.screenY
  });
 jQuery(e.target).trigger(newEvent);    
}
});
```

how can i make it browser compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Use as in your param `e` not `event`:

```
jQuery("#calendar").mousedown(function (e) {
    if (e.button === 2) {
        var newEvent = $.extend($.Event("click"), {
            which: 1,
            clientX: e.clientX,
            clientY: e.clientY,
            pageX: e.pageX,
            pageY: e.pageY,
            screenX: e.screenX,
            screenY: e.screenY
        });
        jQuery(e.target).trigger(newEvent);
    }
});
```